# Getting error "Too many levels of symbolic links" when trying to navigate ubuntu

Tags: symbolic-link

I'm just trying to navigate from the root to my desktop in ubuntu, but anytime I try to put "cd Desktop/" (relative path) Or even "cd ~/Desktop" (absolute path), I keep getting the error "Too many levels of Symbolic links" and it won't let me navigate. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Does `cd && ls -lA` reveal anything special with "Desktop" ?

Comment: It _should_ read similar to `drwxr-xr-x  2 hannu hannu     4096 sep 12 10:21 Desktop` and nothing else.

Comment: It has that and at the very end adds -> root/Desktop

Comment: And do you have and initial `d`rwx... ? I suspect there is an `l`(lower case L) - if so that is not "usual" and might be directly related to your problem; i.e. "/home/$USER/Desktop" is normally a folder, not a symbolic link.

Comment: Ah yes, there isn't a `d`, it has the `l` like you said. What it says is `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root (date and time)`

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
cd
rm -r Desktop
mkdir Desktop
cd ~/Desktop # Now you can access the newly created Desktop directory.
```

Now you can access your newly created Desktop directory in the usual way and copy files into it.

Comment: I was in my home directory, if I cd out of it and go back into the mnt directory (where my desktop directory is) it just brings me right back to where I was

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I misspoke. I went back into ubuntu and navigated around, my Desktop 'directory' IS in my root path (~/Desktop) not in the mnt directory, and that's where the issue is occurring. There is no Desktop directory in my mnt directory